# How to disabled dates after the disabled ones if selecting before the disabled dates?

Tags: javascript, date, date-range, daterangepicker

[image]

So this picture describes the problem good enough I hope. I want to disable the opportunity to select the dates after the disabled ones, in this examples April 10, 11, 12. So if I pick the start date at April 1 I want to disable the dates after 12 April.

Hope it is possibly to understand my problem.

The calendar system is from http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: In a generalized way, starting from the currently selected date (start point), you want to skip ahead to the next disabled date and disable all dates from there onwards (because either they already are disabled anyway, or they should become disabled now). With the aim of preventing users to mark a range that **contains** any disabled dates. Right?

Comment: Use the apply.daterangepicker to check where in the calendar was clicked. Check this date with disabled dates, find closest date that is higher then clicked date. At last set the max date to this date.

Try it like this, post your code where you are stuck, I will follow up.

Comment: @Wimanicesir From the docs it appears that `apply.daterangepicker` is only fired when the range is readily picked and the user clicks on "apply". There seems to be no event that is fired when the start date is clicked.

Comment: Yeah you are right. But can't you add your own event listener? However, I'm wondering if it's even possible to update the options of the calendar without reinitialising it.